# how do we update information from open weather API after a button click in an android app

Tags: android, json, api, weatherdata

I am building a simple android app ,How do i refresh data from the open weather API,i have tried looking at a few ope source weather apps but haven't been succeeded.

Comment: Request the data again?

Comment: I think there are many more open-source API available if you want the API than you can just get it from google search. If you already have API and just want to refresh data than better to post your pice of code. It will make it easy for others to understand your issue.